# Bhairava Agamas: English translations of available manuscripts

Tags: scripture, reference-request, agamas, bhairava

Are there any legit available archived manuscripts of Bhairava Agamas that have been preserved?

It is well known that there were 64 of them, but a lot of them had been lost, Abhinavgupta, in his Tantraloka has compiled a few of them and cited that are usually read. But is any original of the few that have been left and translated into English?

[I know tantraloka has been translated to English.]